# Schema is missing if using sql file instead of psql

Tags: postgresql

I'm not very familiar with postgresql.

I tried to setup a postgres db (using kubernetes helm chart) to use it with gitea:

```
psql -U postgres

CREATE ROLE gitea WITH LOGIN PASSWORD 'gitea';
CREATE DATABASE gitea WITH OWNER gitea TEMPLATE template0 ENCODING UTF8 LC_COLLATE 'en_US.UTF-8' LC_CTYPE 'en_US.UTF-8';
\connect gitea;
CREATE SCHEMA gitea;
GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA gitea TO gitea;
ALTER USER gitea SET search_path=gitea;
```

This is working well. (I don't understand every command, so maybe this can be optimized.)

Now I'm trying to configure the helm chart for the postgres db initial setup to get the same result as shown above.

```
primary:
  initdb:
    scripts:
      init.sql: |
        CREATE ROLE gitea WITH LOGIN PASSWORD 'gitea';
        CREATE DATABASE gitea WITH OWNER gitea TEMPLATE template0 ENCODING UTF8 LC_COLLATE 'en_US.UTF-8' LC_CTYPE 'en_US.UTF-8';
        CREATE SCHEMA gitea;
        GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA gitea TO gitea;
        ALTER USER gitea SET search_path=gitea;
        GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE gitea TO gitea;
```

But this time I do get the error

```
pq: schema "gitea" does not exist
```

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which command gives that error? Or, is it that whatever is processing that YAML file is sending that entire block of SQL as a single command?